# Replace column in one file with column from another using awk?

Tags: replace, awk

I have two files:

```
f1:
111 aaa 444
222 bbb 555
333 ccc 666

f2:
111 333 000 444
222 444 111 555
333 555 555 666
```

How can I replace second column in "f1", with third column from "f2" using awk?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**try:**

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$3;next}{$2=a[FNR]}1' f2 f1
```

**Output:**

```
111 000 444
222 111 555
333 555 666
```

**Explanation of the above code:**

- `FNR==NR` allows you to work with one entire file at a time. In this case it is the file `f2`. `NR` and `FNR` both contain line numbers with the difference being `FNR` gets reset to 1 when a new file is read where as `NR` continues to increment.
- While we are working with `f2` file, we are creating an array called `a` using line number (`NR`) as the `key` and third column (`$3`) as the value. `next` allows us to skip the rest of the action block.
- Once `f2` file ends, we start to work on `f1` file. `NR==FNR` condition will not become false as `FNR` will increment from 1 and `NR` won't. So only second action block `{$2=a[FNR]}` will be worked upon.
- What this block does is it re-assigns second column value to array value by looking up the line number.
- `1` at the end prints the line. It returns true, and in `awk` true statements results in printing of the line.
- `f2 f1` is the order of files defined. Since we want to create an array from file `f2` we put that first.

Comment: @saloua I added some explanation. Hope that helps!

Comment: My use case is very slightly different (only slightly). The difference is I had a comma delimited file for f1 and f2 instead of space delimited. I tried your same command with `-F,` option but the output file did not have comma in that case. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @Ganesh (I know this is old but…) pass the argument `-vOFS=,` to awk. OFS is the output field separator. (You can do the same thing inside the awk program inside a BEGIN block: ala `BEGIN{OFS=","}`)