# Awk: substituting values in a column based on input from another file

Tags: awk

I used the awk one liner from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846476/replace-column-in-one-file-with-column-from-another-using-awk) question to solve a problem of mine that was similar.  However, not really knowing Awk I have no idea how it works.  Can anyone explain how the script functions?  I'd like to understand it so I can apply it in different situations.

Below is the one liner from the link:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$3;next}{$2=a[FNR]}1' f2 f1
```

I know that `FNR=NR` part of it is what makes sure that the lines in file one are matched to the same line number in file 2.  And obviously $3 and $2 correspond to the third and second fields respectively.  But I am perplexed what the "1" at the end of the code does and I'm a bit confused by the "a".  I assume it represents the file names.

Comment: The `a` is the name of the array variable. `1` is shorthand for `{print}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk will process each file in turn line by line. Awk will keep track of the current line number in the current file (`FNR` variable) and also the total number of lines seen so far (`NR` variable). The condition `FNR==NR` can only be true while awk is reading the first file.

`a[NR]=$3` sets the array element indexed at NR to hold the value of the third field.

An awk program is largely composed of `condition {action}` pairs. For the current line, each condition is checked and if true then the action block is executed. If the condition is missing, the action block will be executed -- this is the case for the `{$2=a[FNR]}` block. If the condition is present but the action block is absent, the default action is to print $0 which is the current line after any transformations. Since a non-zero number is equivalent to true, then `1` instructs awk to perform the default action for every line.

The reason the first file is not printed is due to the `next` instruction in the first block.

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate the detailed answer.  That clears things up for me.