# Replace a column from one file with a column from another file?

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have file1 as follows,

```
ATOM     48  O   ILE A   6       7.686  11.253  -7.457  1.00 27.81           O
ATOM     49  CB  ILE A   6       6.898  13.596  -9.634  1.00 26.66           C
ATOM     50  CG1 ILE A   6       8.370  13.338  -9.831  1.00 24.73           C
ATOM     51  CG2 ILE A   6       6.637  15.204  -9.788  1.00 26.32           C
ATOM     52  CD1 ILE A   6       8.976  13.780 -11.270  1.00 32.46           C
```

Now, I would like to replace $11 column with another column from file2, to get output as follows,

```
ATOM     48  O   ILE A   6       7.686  11.253  -7.457  1.00 -28.81          O
ATOM     49  CB  ILE A   6       6.898  13.596  -9.634  1.00  30.66          C
ATOM     50  CG1 ILE A   6       8.370  13.338  -9.831  1.00 -56.73          C
ATOM     51  CG2 ILE A   6       6.637  15.204  -9.788  1.00  46.32          C
ATOM     52  CD1 ILE A   6       8.976  13.780 -11.270  1.00  4.46           C
```

file2 is as follows,

```
-28.81 
30.66
-56.73
46.32
4.46
```

I have tried to write this code works okay but formatting is altered.

```
for i in {1..798}
do 
paste -d, <(awk -F' ' 'NR == '$i' {print $1 "  " $2 "   " $3 "     " $4 "     " $5 "     " $6 "    " $7 "    " $8 "    " $9 "    " $10 }' 1IV7_bfac_try.pdb) <(awk -F' ' ' NR == '$i' {print $0}' colm_awk) <(awk -F' ' 'NR == '$i' {print $12}' 1IV7_bfac_try.pdb) >> new
done
```

Any help with awk or something would be useful, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace column in one file with column from another using awk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846476/replace-column-in-one-file-with-column-from-another-using-awk)

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c11[NR]=$1; next} {$11=c11[FNR]}1' file2 file1
```

Comment: This will normalize the spacing.  You can pipe to `column -t` to put back to tabular form.  To preserve the spacing you should not parse the line and can do a string replacement instead

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846476/replace-column-in-one-file-with-column-from-another-using-awk)

**Input**

```
::::::::::::::
f1
::::::::::::::
ATOM     48  O   ILE A   6       7.686  11.253  -7.457  1.00 27.81           O
ATOM     49  CB  ILE A   6       6.898  13.596  -9.634  1.00 26.66           C
ATOM     50  CG1 ILE A   6       8.370  13.338  -9.831  1.00 24.73           C
ATOM     51  CG2 ILE A   6       6.637  15.204  -9.788  1.00 26.32           C
ATOM     52  CD1 ILE A   6       8.976  13.780 -11.270  1.00 32.46           C
::::::::::::::
f2
::::::::::::::
-28.81
30.66
-56.73
46.32
4.46
```

**Output**

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next}{$11=a[FNR]}1' f2 f1

ATOM 48 O ILE A 6 7.686 11.253 -7.457 1.00 -28.81 O
ATOM 49 CB ILE A 6 6.898 13.596 -9.634 1.00 30.66 C
ATOM 50 CG1 ILE A 6 8.370 13.338 -9.831 1.00 -56.73 C
ATOM 51 CG2 ILE A 6 6.637 15.204 -9.788 1.00 46.32 C
ATOM 52 CD1 ILE A 6 8.976 13.780 -11.270 1.00 4.46 C
```

**Explanation:**

- `FNR==NR` allows you to work with one entire file at a time. In this case it is the file `f2`. `NR` and `FNR` both contain line numbers with the difference being `FNR` gets reset to 1 when a new file is read where as `NR` continues to increment.
- While we are working with `f2` file, we are creating an array called `a` using line number (`NR`) as the `key` and first column (`$1`) as the value. `next` allows us to skip the rest of the action block.
- Once `f2` file ends, we start to work on `f1` file. `NR==FNR` condition will not become false as `FNR` will increment from 1 and `NR` won't. So only eleventh action block `{$11=a[FNR]}` will be worked upon.
- What this block does is it re-assigns second column value to array value by looking up the line number.
- `1` at the end prints the line. It returns true, and in `awk` true statements results in printing of the line.
- `f2 f1` is the order of files defined. Since we want to create an array from file `f2` we put that first.

On the formatting, another interesting example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203066/column-replacement-with-awk-with-retaining-the-format)

```
gawk '
NR==FNR { f1[NR]=$0; next }
{
    split(f1[FNR],flds,FS,seps)
    flds[11]=$1
    for (i=1;i in flds;i++)
        printf "%s%s", flds[i], seps[i]
    print ""
}
' f1 f2
```

Comment: This give only ATOM column and column from file2 , but I just want to replace $11 column, why there is no print option in this awk command ?

Comment: added explanation. See if you want any improvisation