# How to replace some particular column values in a file from the columns of other file

Tags: awk, sed, cut

I know similar questions has been answered  many time on SO.
(one example is `here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846476/replace-column-in-one-file-with-column-from-another-using-awk`)

But, this is something unique in my case as I need to take care of a particular pattern.

header of my file1, that I want to get updated, is

```
  3    6  0  6.0361821  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
      0.994429353    0.000000000    0.000000000
      0.000000000    0.994429353    0.000000000
      0.000000000    0.000000000    2.469627493
           1  'A '    63548.626894188397     
           2  'B '    169717.29799472401     
           3  'C '    25598.367262405900     
    1    2      0.7458220147      0.7458220147      1.8031927376   << need to be updated from here
    2    2      0.2486073382      0.2486073382      0.6664347554
    3    1      0.2486073382      0.2486073382      2.2628589536
    4    1      0.7458220147      0.7458220147      0.2067685394
    5    3      0.7458220147      0.7458220147      1.0275486366
    6    3      0.2486073382      0.2486073382      1.4420788564  << upto here
 T
     21.3496599      0.0000000      0.0000000
      0.0000000     21.3496599      0.0000000
      0.0000000      0.0000000     24.1101752
    1
     -7.6119990     -0.0000000      0.0000000
      0.0000000     -7.6119990      0.0000000
      0.0000000      0.0000000     -7.0331945
    2
     -7.6119990      0.0000000      0.0000000
     -0.0000000     -7.6119990      0.0000000
      0.0000000      0.0000000     -7.0331945
    3
      3.4711749      0.0000000      0.0000000
```

I need to update the `$2`, `$3` and `$4` of `file1` from  `$ESPi"th` line to `"$ESPf"th`  with `$1`, `$2` and `$3` of `file2` (mentioned below). The spaces in file1 should not change while updating. Here `$ESPi"th` and `"$ESPf"th` represents 8th line and 13th lines, respectively and changes case to case.

file2 is

```
0.750000000 0.750000000 0.730147661   << with these data 
0.250000000 0.250000000 0.269852339
0.250000000 0.250000000 0.916275414
0.750000000 0.750000000 0.083724586
0.750000000 0.750000000 0.416074343
0.250000000 0.250000000 0.583925657  < upto these data
```

I have tried to do my job with.

```
#!/bin/bash
for j in `seq "$ESPi" 1 "$ESPf"`    # ESPi and ESPf are 8 and 13, respectively here and change case by case.
do
ESP1=$(cat file1 | head -n "$j" | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}')
ESP2=$(cat file1 | head -n "$j" | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}')
ESP3=$(cat file1 | head -n "$j" | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $5}')

for k in `seq 1 1 "$NELEMENTS"`  # $NELEMENTS is six here.
do
qeIN1=$(cat file2 | head -n "$k" | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')
qeIN2=$(cat file2 | head -n "$k" | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')
qeIN3=$(cat file2 | head -n "$k" | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}')
sed  's/'$ESP1'/'$qeIN1'/g' file1
sed  's/'$ESP2'/'$qeIN2'/g' file1
sed  's/'$ESP3'/'$qeIN3'/g' file1
done
done
```

This gives me

```
3    6  0  6.0361821  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
      0.994429353    0.000000000    0.000000000
      0.000000000    0.994429353    0.000000000
      0.000000000    0.000000000    2.469627493
           1  'A '    63548.626894188397
           2  'B '    169717.29799472401
           3  'C '    25598.367262405900
    1    2      0.7458220147      0.7458220147      1.8031927376
    2    2      0.750000000      0.750000000      0.6664347554
    3    1      0.750000000      0.750000000      2.2628589536
    4    1      0.7458220147      0.7458220147      0.2067685394
    5    3      0.7458220147      0.7458220147      1.0275486366
    6    3      0.750000000      0.750000000      1.4420788564
 T
     21.3496599      0.0000000      0.0000000
      0.0000000     21.3496599      0.0000000
      0.0000000      0.0000000     24.1101752
    1
     -7.6119990     -0.0000000      0.0000000
      0.0000000     -7.6119990      0.0000000
      0.0000000      0.0000000     -7.0331945
    2
     -7.6119990      0.0000000      0.0000000
     -0.0000000     -7.6119990      0.0000000
      0.0000000      0.0000000     -7.0331945
    3
      3.4711749      0.0000000      0.0000000
```

The expected output is

```
  3    6  0  6.0361821  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
      0.994429353    0.000000000    0.000000000
      0.000000000    0.994429353    0.000000000
      0.000000000    0.000000000    2.469627493
           1  'A '    63548.626894188397
           2  'B '    169717.29799472401
           3  'C '    25598.367262405900
    1    2      0.750000000      0.750000000      0.730147661
    2    2      0.250000000      0.250000000      0.269852339
    3    1      0.250000000      0.250000000      0.916275414
    4    1      0.750000000      0.750000000      0.083724586
    5    3      0.750000000      0.750000000      0.416074343
    6    3      0.250000000      0.250000000      0.583925657
 T
     21.3496599      0.0000000      0.0000000
      0.0000000     21.3496599      0.0000000
      0.0000000      0.0000000     24.1101752
    1
     -7.6119990     -0.0000000      0.0000000
      0.0000000     -7.6119990      0.0000000
      0.0000000      0.0000000     -7.0331945
    2
     -7.6119990      0.0000000      0.0000000
     -0.0000000     -7.6119990      0.0000000
      0.0000000      0.0000000     -7.0331945
    3
      3.4711749      0.0000000      0.0000000
```

I am looking for shell (bash) script.

Comment: Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net, fix the issues it tells you about, and then repost if you still need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

ESPi=8
ESPf=13

python > file1.new <<EOF
import sys, re
write = sys.stdout.write
espi = $ESPi
espf = $ESPf
repls = {2:0, 3:1, 4:2}
with open("file1") as f1, open("file2") as f2:
    for i in range(espi - 1): write(next(f1))
    for i in range(espf - espi + 1):
        line = next(f1)
        toks = next(f2).split()
        for col, rcol in repls.items():
            pat = "(\s*)((\S+\s+){{{col}}})(\S+)(.*)".format(col=col)
            repl = r"\g<1>\g<2>{val}\g<5>".format(val=toks[rcol])
            line = re.sub(pat, repl, line)
        write(line)
    for line in f1: write(line)
EOF

mv file1.new file1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
gawk 'FNR==NR{ a[i++]=$0 }
      FNR!=NR && FNR>=8 && FNR<=13{ split(a[j++],b); $3=b[1]; $4=b[2]; $5=b[3]; }
      FNR!=NR{ print $0 }'  file2 file1
```

FNR = The input record number in the current input file.
NR = The total number of input records seen so far.

Line numbers 8 and 13 are fixed in this script because no info is given on how to determine these values.

EDIT:

I forgot about preserving whitespace, next one should do that:

```
gawk 'FNR==NR{ a[i++]=$0 }
      FNR!=NR && FNR>=8 && FNR<=13{ split(a[j++],b); sub($3,b[1]); sub($4,b[2]); sub($5,b[3]); }
      FNR!=NR{ print $0 }'  file2 file1
```

Comment: gawk doesn't seem to preserve the whitespace as needed, so I cheated... (see other answer)

Comment: @alaniwi gawk preserves whitespace just fine if you write code that's intended to preserve whitespace. The issue here is the script, not the tool.

Comment: Yes, Luuk's new script works nicely, thanks. Still it's only a matter of tradition that shell scripts tend to invoke tools like awk and sed rather than python. It's fairly reliably installed with the OS these days, I think, but it still feels like cheating :-)

Comment: @alaniwi it's not a matter of tradition, it's just simpler and clearer. I posted an awk answer so you can see what I mean.

Comment: @EdMorton I could understand an argument based on startup overhead or portability, but which is "clearer" sounds like mostly a question of familiarity.

Comment: @alaniwi there is code that is generally easier to read than other code both by people familiar with the given tool/language and those unfamiliar with it - that's what I mean by clearer. If such code is also briefer then we get conciseness which is always a goal when writing software. Since conciseness is brevity+clarity that implies there is such a thing as objective clarity. My main comment was to just disagree with your unfounded statement that "it's only a matter of tradition that shell scripts tend to invoke tools like awk and sed rather than python".

Answer (score 1):

This will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { new[NR]=$0; next }
(espi <= FNR) && (FNR <= espf) {
    split(new[FNR-espi+1],vals)
    i = 0
    while ( match($0,/[^[:space:]]+/) ) {
        printf "%s%s", substr($0,1,RSTART-1), (++i >= 3 ? vals[i-2] : substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH))
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
{ print }
```

.

```
$ awk -v espi=8 -v espf=13 -f tst.awk file2 file1
  3    6  0  6.0361821  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
      0.994429353    0.000000000    0.000000000
      0.000000000    0.994429353    0.000000000
      0.000000000    0.000000000    2.469627493
           1  'A '    63548.626894188397
           2  'B '    169717.29799472401
           3  'C '    25598.367262405900
    1    2      0.750000000      0.750000000      0.730147661
    2    2      0.250000000      0.250000000      0.269852339
    3    1      0.250000000      0.250000000      0.916275414
    4    1      0.750000000      0.750000000      0.083724586
    5    3      0.750000000      0.750000000      0.416074343
    6    3      0.250000000      0.250000000      0.583925657
 T
     21.3496599      0.0000000      0.0000000
      0.0000000     21.3496599      0.0000000
      0.0000000      0.0000000     24.1101752
    1
     -7.6119990     -0.0000000      0.0000000
      0.0000000     -7.6119990      0.0000000
      0.0000000      0.0000000     -7.0331945
    2
     -7.6119990      0.0000000      0.0000000
     -0.0000000     -7.6119990      0.0000000
      0.0000000      0.0000000     -7.0331945
    3
      3.4711749      0.0000000      0.0000000
```

Comment: Do you care to share why my last solution should not work with 'any awk in any shell' ?

Comment: I haven't looked at it. What makes you think it wouldn't?

Comment: @Luuk having looked at it now, it won't work in any awk because `sub($4,b[2])`, for example, won't replace `$4` with `b[2]`, it'll replace the first string that matches the regexp described by `$4` with `b[2]` so it could replace part/all of `$3` if it matches a regexp described by `$4`. For example if `$3` is `12345` and `$4` is `2.4` and `b[2]` is `97` then `sub($4,b[2])` will turn `$3` into `1975` and leave `$4` as-is.