# Replace rows in bash with rows from another file matching column of another file

Tags: bash, join, replace

I have found a similar question to mine:
[Replace column in one file with column from another using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846476/replace-column-in-one-file-with-column-from-another-using-awk)

However, I am unable to understand this explanation and therefore adapt it to my own (different) problem. That question seems to be about replacing a value from the equivalent *line number* in the second file whereas what I need is to replace it based on a common/lookup field.

Could somebody please help and offer me an explicit explanation as to how I can adapt the code in that other question, or provide a solution based on my previous paragraph?

I have file 1:

```
sample_1    group_1
sample_2    group_1
sample_3    group_1
sample_4    group_2
sample_5    group_2
sample_6    group_2
sample_7    group_3
sample_8    group_3
sample_9    group_3
```

and file 2:

```
sample_8    group_3.1
sample_9    group_3.1
```

I want to replace the rows in column 2, file 1 with the matching rows of file 2, column 1, so the result is:

```
sample_1    group_1
sample_2    group_1
sample_3    group_1
sample_4    group_2
sample_5    group_2
sample_6    group_2
sample_7    group_3
sample_8    group_3.1
sample_9    group_3.1
```

The nearest I have got is to do a left join: `join -a1 -j 1 -o 1.1,1.2,2.2 <(sort -k1 file_1) <(sort -k1 file_2)`

which gives me:

```
sample_1 group_1 
sample_2 group_1 
sample_3 group_1 
sample_4 group_2 
sample_5 group_2 
sample_6 group_2 
sample_7 group_3 
sample_8 group_3 group_3.1
sample_9 group_3 group_3.1
```

Then I thought I could drop the second column if the file 1 second column was repeated in the third column, but of course this does not happen.

Comment: You would be better off asking for more detail on the original question's answer rather than posting a duplicate. Continuing to post duplicates when it's been pointed out to you that it's the wrong thing to do borders on sociopathy :-)

Comment: How am I supposed to know that it's a duplicate? The problems don't even seem the same. I am looking to replace specific rows of file 1, column 2 with the rows of column 2, file 2 where the rows of column 1 match in both files. The other question is asking how to replace a whole column tout court with no reference to matching columns.

Comment: Luther, if this isn't a dupe, then you would have been better off stating *why* you thought so (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). Simply stating (effectively) "I've been told it's a dupe so I'm going to post it again" is not a good strategy :-) See my edits to give an example. Basically, if you can convince SO that it *is* different, SO will allow it. Re-opening based on this new info.